# Cómo combino en un nuevo dataframe los datos de dos columnas en r

Tags: r

Tengo un dataframe con muchas columnas. Una de esas columnas pongamos que se llama animales1 y la otra animales2.
Animales1: vaca, perro, gato, serpiente, ...
Animales2: gato, cerdo, perro, perro, ...

Quiero crear un dataframe con una columna llamada animales que tenga todos los animales de Animales1  y Animales2 y con otra columna con el recuento de animales que hay en total, de manera que contabilice cada animal tantas veces como aparezcan en ambas columnas (por ejemplo, perro aparece 1 vez en la columna Animales1 y 2 veces en la columna Animales2, por lo que en la columna de recuento tendría que salir 3).

He probado con merge pero me da error.

¿Alguien podría decirme qué código usar?

Gracias.

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer la sección [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). En este sitio no resolvemos tareas y/o proyectos. Para cada pregunta es necesario que agregues un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) para que podamos ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

De partida, para preguntar debes [crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Para entender el origen de lo que posees y ayudarte de mejor manera.

Me tomé la libertad de crear un ejemplo por ti (a pesar que quizás no refleje 100% tu problema, ya que no estoy en tus zapatos):

```
df <- data.frame(id=1:4,
                 animales1 = c('vaca',
                               'perro',
                               'gato',
                               'serpiente'),
                 animales2 = c('gato',
                               'cerdo',
                               'perro',
                               'perro'))
```

Para realizar las acciones que comentas, lo más práctico es utilizar librerías del `tidyverse`. En este caso en particular las dos útiles para este fin son `tidyr` and `dpylr`.

`pivot_longer` mezcla las columnas en una sola, le puse `-id` para demostrar que se pueden excluir las columnas que quieras, luego `select` para eliminar la columna que queda con los nombres originales de las columnas que se mezclaron. `group_by` agrupa el `tibble` para calcular las etiquetas repetidas de `animales` utilizando la función `summarise`.

```
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-id,
               names_to = 'columna_original',
               values_to = 'animal') %>% 
  select(-columna_original) %>% 
  group_by(animal) %>% 
  summarise(total = n())
# # A tibble: 5 × 2
#   animal    total
#   <chr>     <int>
# 1 cerdo         1
# 2 gato          2
# 3 perro         3
# 4 serpiente     1
# 5 vaca          1
```

Ahora, para dejar el resultado en un `data.frame` simplemente añade `%>% as.data.frame()`